# The unit vector in the direction of u

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm trying to work my way through a linear algebra assignment, and I'm struggling with a few questions. This is one of them.

I'm completely lost at question A. I think that B's answer is true, but it seems a bit too obvious for me to be sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Define (in the question or in a comment) the dot product of two arbitrary vectors (just checking whether you know) in terms of their components. And the norm of a vector in terms of its components, while you're at it. From these two definitions, it should be easy to work your way to the answer.

Comment: What is the length of $u$ and what is the length of $\lambda u$, where $\lambda$ is a scalar? What value(s) must $\lambda$ have so that $\lambda u$ has unit length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is the definition of what a unit vector in the direction of û is. By dividing the vector û by it's magnitude u, you can see that the new vector has a magnitude of 1--try it out! You'll see that by the end of finding the magnitude of the new vector û/u, you'll end up with u/u which is 1.

Comment: The norm of $(1,1,1)$ is not $1$, it's $\sqrt3$.

Comment: The dot product of $(1,1,1)$ with itself is not $1$, it's $3$. I have no idea which $1$ you're talking about in your answer.

Comment: It's hard to comprehend because it's false. Let $u=(1,1,1)$. Then $u\cdot u=3$ and $\|u\|^2=(\sqrt3)^2=3$, so $u\cdot u=\|u\|^2$ and the statement is true. Again, I have no idea where you are getting the $1$ from.

Comment: Because I'm stupid and forgot everything I learned the past decade.